# Shouldn't informative comments be left for a sufficient amount of time to be read by the intended reader?

Tags: discussion, deleted-comments

In [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/45912/changing-phd-group-yes-or-not), the OP, who is a newcomer, answered to two questions that have been posted as comments directly under her original question, by commenting jakebeal's answer. This indeed doesn't get the commenters notified of the responses.

I've left a comment to the OP by saying that she had answered under the wrong comment list and that her responses would not have been notified to the other commenters.

My comment was deleted in an hour or so, without giving the OP enough time to read it, moving her comments and avoid this mistake in the future. Moreover, also one of the OP's comments was deleted, while the other was left (it is not clear according to which criterion).

So: shouldn't informative comments be left for a sufficient amount of time to be read by the intended readers, especially when they are newcomers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, of course informative comments should be left. For the record, I did not handle these comments. For the 3 comments you are talking about, the information from the one regarding the OP’s country was reposted (mods cannot move comments) in the correct place. Another comment said "thank you! I will". Presumably this was in response to a comment by Alexandros. Leaving the comment where it was and/or reporting it with a ping to Alexandros from a different user would be odd. Leaving it where it was, adding a comment about what the comment was referring to and adding another comment pinging Alexandros to inform him of the issue, seems overkill for a thanks comment. The final comment about how to properly comment is only useful to the OP of the original question. The [ping notification should still show up in the OP's inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19092/255554), so there is no need to repost it. In this case I think the way the comments were handled was fine.